# How to mock chained dependencies in Java using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have Class A, which has a dependency on class B. And class B has again has a dependency on class C. Structure looks like:

```
Class A(){
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public void someMethod(){
        b.callAnotherMethodAndGetValue();
    }
}

Class B(){
    @Autowired
    private C c;

    public void callAnotherMethodAndGetValue(){
        c.callAnother();
    }
}

Class ATest(){
    @Spy
    private B b;

    public void someMethod(){
        // it goes into this method, and throws null pointer exception at
        // c.callAnother(); as c is null.
        b.callAnotherMethodAndGetValue();
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can let the stack flow to `c.callAnother` from Test Cases. Without doing when then at `b.callAnotherMethodAndGetValue();`

Answer (score 5):

You need to mock C: and **not** spy on b:

```
@Mock
C c;

@InjectMocks
B b;
@Test
public void someMethod(){
  b.callAnotherMethodAndGetValue();
}
```

Off cause you'd make your life easier if you used *constructor injection*!

---

> I am writing the test cases for Class A. Inside Test For Class A , I should do @InjectMocks A a and should do `a.someMethod()` – Jyoti Yadav

Then the test should look like this:

```
@Mock
B b;

@InjectMocks
A a;

@Test
public void someMethod(){
  a.someMethod();
}
```

Comment: I guess there is a gap here , I am writing the test cases for Class A.Inside Test For Class A , I should do @InjectMocks A a and should do a.someMethod() .

Comment: This will throw null pointer on b.callAnotherMethodAndgetValue for c as null .As i dont want to do when().then() for b.callAnother....

Comment: @JyotiYadav Works perfectly for me using Mockitos `MockitoJUnit.rule()` instead of a explicit runner class. But I coudn't check with the `@Autowired` annotation...

Comment: @JyotiYadav *"As i dont want to do when().then() for b.callAnother"* That wouldn'd work anyway since with this form Mockito cannot prevent the method from beeing actually invoked. It only replaces the result *after* invocation of the method.  You would need the `doReturn().when().methodToCall()` form or `doNothing().when()...` since your method has a  `void` return value...